# Kafka Topic Naming Clarity

Tags: apache-kafka, naming-conventions

There is a Kafka topic already with the name: `x.y.z` Can I create a new topic with the name `x.y`?

I have already gone through [this resource](https://riccomini.name/how-paint-bike-shed-kafka-topic-naming-conventions), but could not find anything related to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create any topic that you want, but the name must be unique name.

Kafka allow you to create how many topics that you want.